# java - Recursive maze solver not working

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, maze

**I have looked at every post with this problem, every guide, every algorithm, and I still cannot find an answer for my problem.** The weird thing is that it doesn't cause any errors, but for every maze it says that it's unsolvable and marks the beginning as a dead end.

I am staring at my code for hours and I cannot figure out what I did wrong!
My code:

(Other non-important classes - MazeSymbol = enum with symbol names and their string, Position = a row/column class, Coordinate = class that contains a MazeSymbol and a Position))

Maze.java:

```
private Coordinate[][] map;
private Position start;
private Position goal;
private ArrayList<Coordinate> solutionPath;
boolean solveable;

public Maze(Coordinate[][] map, Position start, Position goal){
    this.start=start;
    this.map=map;
    this.goal=goal;
    this.solutionPath=new ArrayList<>();
    this.solveable = solveMaze(Coordinate.fromMaze(start, this)); //fromMaze takes a position and finds it's symbol.
}
public boolean isSolveable(){
    return solveable;
}
private boolean solveMaze(Coordinate c){
    System.out.println("Solving - "+c.getPosition().row+","+c.getPosition().column);
     if(!c.getPosition().isOnMaze(this)){//Checks if it is between the bounds of the maze (larger than 0 and smaller than length both for X and Y)
         System.out.println(c.getPosition().row+","+c.getPosition().column+"Isnt on maze! ");
         return false;
     }
     if(c.getPosition().equals(goal)){
         System.out.println(c.getPosition().row+","+c.getPosition().column+"Is goal!");
         return true;
     }
     if(!c.getSymbol().equals(MazeSymbol.OPEN)){//If it isnt an open path - walked/dead end/wall
         System.out.println(+c.getPosition().row+","+c.getPosition().column+" isn't open!(it's "+c.getSymbol()+")");
         return false;
     }
     map[c.getPosition().getRow()][c.getPosition().getColumn()] = new Coordinate(c.getPosition(), MazeSymbol.PATH);//Replace the open path sign with a walked path sign
     solutionPath.add(c);//Add the coordinate to the solution path
     if(solveMaze(c.setPosition(c.getPosition().positionAbove())))return true;//row-1                  
     if(solveMaze(c.setPosition(c.getPosition().positionLeft())))return true;//column+1
     if(solveMaze(c.setPosition(c.getPosition().positionBelow())))return true;//row+1
     if(solveMaze(c.setPosition(c.getPosition().positionRight())))return true;//column-1
     map[c.getPosition().getRow()][c.getPosition().getColumn()] = c.setSymbol(MazeSymbol.DEAD_END);//If none was the path, mark it as a dead end
     return false;
    }
```

Please help! When I insert this extremely simple maze:

{"O","W","W"},

{"O","O","W"},

{"W","O","O"}

It says it is not solveable, and the **output**:

XWW

OOW

WOO

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Changed this line

```
map[c.getPosition().getRow()][c.getPosition().getColumn()] = new Coordinate(c.getPosition(), MazeSymbol.PATH);
```

and now it isnt working at all, it just gives a StackOverflowError in 2 lines then in the 3rd one over and over again:

1. `System.out.println("Solving - "+c.getPosition().row+","+c.getPosition().column);`
2. `if(solveMaze(c.setPosition(c.getPosition().positionAbove())))return true;`
3. `if(solveMaze(c.setPosition(c.getPosition().positionRight())))return true;`

Comment: pls explain the problem scenario

Comment: What does it print when you test it on the simple maze?

Comment: What do "O", "W","X" stand for?

Comment: Yes, printed output would be useful.  I'm not sure why you're marking nodes as dead ends, and that may be the problem.  The way I've always seen this algorithm done involves marking positions that you've searched and then ignoring marked nodes to avoid getting stuck in a loop.  This is actually always guaranteed to terminate.

Comment: the problem is most probably in `c.setPosition(`. I don't know what is your coordinate class but if setPosition changes `c`. then after above check you are passing wrong values to following checks

Comment: @RealSkeptic O = Open path, W = Wall, X = Dead end, P = Path found

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, because you didn't give us the exact code of `Coordinate`, but assuming that all the `set` operations actually set the information in the `Coordinate` instance, the problem is that you change the symbol of `c` in this line:

```
 map[c.getPosition().getRow()][c.getPosition().getColumn()] = c.setSymbol(MazeSymbol.PATH);//Replace the open path sign with a walked path sign
```

Now your `c` is marked as `PATH` rather than `OPEN`. Then you make a recursive call. Let's say it got to the direction below, which is where it's supposed to see that it's open. You set the position of `c`, but its value is still `PATH`. Then, inside the recursive step, it gets to

```
 if(!c.getSymbol().equals(MazeSymbol.OPEN)){//If it isnt an open path - walked/dead end/wall
     System.out.println(+c.getPosition().row+","+c.getPosition().column+" isn't open!(it's "+c.getSymbol()+")");
     return false;
 }
```

And of course, the value is not `OPEN`. So it fails for that position, as well as all the others around the original position.

You need to update the value of `c` from the actual map in the new position, and you don't do that.

**Edit**

I have looked at your question edit. What you did indeed stopped the program from getting a dead end, but it didn't actually solve the issue. You see, what happens now is that you update the position in the map, but when you call the recursive version, the coordinates stays with the value for `OPEN` (or whatever it was in the beginning).

What happens in the recursive step? Let's ignore the directions which are not inside the map. It gets to the

```
 if(!c.getSymbol().equals(MazeSymbol.OPEN)){//If it isnt an open path - walked/dead end/wall
     System.out.println(+c.getPosition().row+","+c.getPosition().column+" isn't open!(it's "+c.getSymbol()+")");
     return false;
 }
```

But no matter what is actually in the map at that coordinate, the value of `c` is still `OPEN`. So it doesn't get inside this `if` block. It believes it's in an open position. So it happily goes to the recursive step again and again. It will go to the position above, and regardless of the fact that the map says it's `P`, will believe it's in an open position, and recurse again, back to the position below, and so on, and so on.

As I already said above, what you have to do is **update the value of c from the new position of the map**. Basically, you're never reading from the map. You never check whether any position in the map is a wall, a path, or open. You only look at `c`, and `c` is not updated from the map, so it doesn't give you the information you need.

Comment: I tried instead of c.setSymbol creating a new coordinate with the PATH symbol and the same position as c. But that gives me a stack overflow error on 2 lines, then a third one over and over again: 1. System.out.println("Solving - "+c.getPosition().row+","+c.getPosition().column); 2.   if(solveMaze(c.setPosition(c.getPosition().positionAbove())))return true;                  3.   if(solveMaze(c.setPosition(c.getPosition().positionRight())))return true;

Comment: Code is really unreadable in a comment. I'm not sure what you wanted to say. You can update your question, write "Edit: I did this and got this" and format the code and errors properly and then leave me a note to look at your updated question. And while you're at it, add the code for your `Coordinate` class, please.

Comment: @NonameSL I have edited my answer to respond to your edit. Please be more helpful to people who are trying to help you: I don't see edits in your question if you don't leave me a comment about it. And not including your `Coordinate` class is not helpful, either. You think it's irrelevant, but every method you call from your code may affect its results, so we need to know what it does exactly. Don't leave people guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that solveMaze should take a Position not a Coordinate, and the maze could simply be MazeSymbol[][].

In fact, I can't really see a use for the Coordinate class at all - it just appears to add confusion by storing another instance of MazeSymbol, which may be different from the global map. I think this is the problem @RealSkeptic is highlighting with the suggestion to:

> update the value of c from the new position of the map

I'd just go one step further, and not bother with the Coordinate class at all.

The key concept here is that when you recurse into an attempt, you update the global state (maze map and solution path); when you recurse out of that attempt, you reverse those changes.

Then the recursive section of solveMaze becomes:

```
private boolean solveMaze(Position p){

    if(!p.isOnMaze(this)) {
        return false;
    }
    if(p.equals(goal)) {
        return true;
    }
    if(!map[p.getRow()][p.getColumn()].equals(MazeSymbol.OPEN)) {   // See NOTE 1
        return false;
    }

    map[p.getRow()][p.getColumn()] = MazeSymbol.PATH;
    solutionPath.add(p);

    if(solveMaze(p.positionAbove())) return true;   // See NOTE 2
    if(solveMaze(p.positionLeft()))  return true;
    if(solveMaze(p.positionBelow())) return true;
    if(solveMaze(p.positionRight())) return true;

    solutionPath.remove(solutionPath.size() - 1);    // See NOTE 3
    map[p.getRow()][p.getColumn()] = MazeSymbol.DEAD_END;

    return false;
}
```

NOTE 1: This checks the symbol from the actual maze, not the symbol in a temporary coordinate passed across the stack.

NOTE 2: I'm assuming that the positionAbove/Left... methods all return a new instance of position and do not modify the instance passed; they probably do, but I can't tell for sure without the code.

NOTE 3: You need to remove invalid attempts from your solution path.

Disclaimer: haven't compiled / run any of this, just typed it in here, so may contain typos etc.

HTH